# How to make a reverse asterisk triangle with JavaScript using 'while' loop

Tags: javascript

My goal for this code is to display a reversed asterisk right triangle, (right angle on upper right side) using the given input that is used in the prompt. Example if the user inputs 5, the output on the html body should be:

```
*****
 ****
  ***
   ** 
    *
```

---

Here is my code, this produces something that is almost what I need, but I'm having trouble adding the spaces as they should, e.g zero spaces in row one, one space in row two, two spaces in row three, etc.

```js
document.write("<table border=1>"); //start table, *set border=0 when finished*

var height, something, spaces;

height = Number(prompt("Please enter a height.")); // prompts for height

something = height; //******place-holder, pick new variable name******

var counter, counter_2;

spaces = 0;
counter = 1;
row = 0;
column = 0;

while (something != 0) // continues until something = 0
{
  document.write("<tr>"); // start row
  while ((row > 0) && (column < height)) {
    document.write("<td>" + " " + "</td>");
    column++;
  }
  while (counter <= height) // continues until counter = height
  {
    document.write("<td>" + "*" + "</td>"); // adds "*"
    counter++; // add 1 to counter
    column++;
  }
  something--; // subtract 1 from "something"
  counter = 1; // reset counter to 1
  height--;
  column = 0;
  row++;
  document.write("</tr>"); // end row
}
document.write("</table>"); // end table
```

Answer (score 0):

Your only one condition was wrong

Instead of

```
while ((row > 0) && (column < height)) {
```

Try

```
while ((row > 0) && (column < row)) {
```

```js
document.write("<table border=1>"); //start table, *set border=0 when finished*

var height,something,spaces;
height = Number(prompt("Please enter a height.")); // prompts for height

something = height; //******place-holder, pick new variable name******
var counter, counter_2;

spaces = 0;
counter = 1;
row=0;
column=0;

while (something != 0) // continues until something = 0
    {
    document.write("<tr>"); // start row
    while ((row > 0) && (column<row))
        {
        document.write("<td>" + " " + "</td>");
        column++;
        }
    while (counter <= height)  // continues until counter = height
        {
        document.write("<td>" + "*" + "</td>"); // adds "*"
        counter++; // add 1 to counter
        column++;
        }
    something--; // subtract 1 from "something"
    counter=1; // reset counter to 1
    height--;
    column=0;
    row++;
    document.write("</tr>"); // end row
    }
document.write("</table>");
```

Answer (score -1):

Your example contains an unnecessary amount of variables. You could achieve the same result using the `height` variable and two `for` loops. It's also a good idea to avoid using variables names that don't aren't very descriptive (i.e. `something`, `count_2`)

```js
var dataOutput = document.querySelector("#data-output");

var height = +prompt("Please enter a height.");

for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < height; rowIndex++) {
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  for (var columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < height; columnIndex++) {
    row.appendChild(document.createElement("td")).textContent = columnIndex < rowIndex ? " " : "*";
  }
  dataOutput.appendChild(row);
}

// use this to remove the border of the table
// dataOutput.parentElement.removeAttribute("border");
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tbody id="data-output">

  </tbody>
</table>
```

If you want to remove the border once your code runs, you just have to unquote the last line.